# Embed Go struct data into binary

Tags: go

I have several hundred records of metadata I need available to my Go program. I would like the data to be compiled into the binary so it just works, avoiding dependencies on additional files to run.

The metadata starts as csv, and I have a another package that processes the csv into structs. The main program uses these structs by importing that package. The csv only changes occasionally.

I learned how to import and export the structs as [gobs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/), but I would need to store those gobs in a file (etc) and load them in at runtime.

I looked at making shared libraries, but those are in ELF format and don't seem to support the native Go structs I need.

I could have the csv-processing package literally print out go code to recreate these struct instances (with say a base64-encoded gob of it), to be built with the main program, but that seems like an awfully roundabout way to go about this.

Is there a simple way to embed this prepared struct data into my binary?

Comment: That's not an awfully roundabout way to go about it. That _is_ the straightforward time-honored way to go about it.

Comment: My only suggestion is not to use base64. That will just bloat your binary. Use hex literals. This will make your source code larger, but who cares, since it's generated sources you shouldn't be reading anyway. And then the compiled version will be smaller, as well as faster to execute (as no base64-decoding will be necessary).

Comment: it may be time-honored and the best option, but it is definitely not straightforward. The part that bothers me the most is that though gobs are "self-describing," the receiving types still need to be defined, so I will have to maintain two separate copies. I suppose I could symlink across packages.

Comment: I don't think the time-honored way includes gobbing.  If you do that, you may as well just embed the original csv as a string in the source code.  The common thing to do would be to just generate struct literals.

Comment: The csv requires some processing, and it rarely changes, so no sense in having to do that on every run when you can do it once (at least in this case).

Comment: Can you not just represent the processed data as struct literals in go source code?

Comment: not really: there are several layers of struct values being other structs

Answer (score 0):

There are a little bit packages which make possible to embed resource (binaries) into your app.

I was using the following:

- I choose [go-resources](https://github.com/omeid/go-resources) to use in production. It generates go source code file contained your data as  hex encoded;
- another useful package: [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) - is real embed your data as a resource into an executable file. But I got some issue for cross-platform building;

I find packages wich doing the same task, but I didn't use it in production:

- https://github.com/pyros2097/go-embed
- https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

Comment: these could all be _part_ of an answer, but they all deal with arbitrary data, not native Go types, which is what I would like to preserve.

Comment: the part about rice appending zipped data to an executable is interesting, but almost all info about it out there is about windows.

Comment: @carilonator You was trying to use gobs to un/serialize data. It is a good way to load data from an external file stored on local disk. Golang has no one way to load data as ready to work raw data like as C/C++ make possible to do.

Comment: You can use following steps:
prepare your data in gobs format, then use a development time file marked, for example, the negative tag "embed" // +build !embed to load your data from a local disk in a development process,
then using go-resources to generate a go file marked tag "embed" and load your data using method is the same as you load your data from a disk.